# Bind a list to a model attribute in SpringBoot

Tags: java, rest, spring-boot

I want to bind the list to an attribute in the model

Controller

```
@GetMapping("search")
public ResponseEntity<SearchResponseWrapper> fetchSearchResults(SearchCriteria searchCriteria) {
}
```

Model

```
public class SearchCriteria {
     public List<String> pageSources;

     ...//some other attribute
     ...//some other attribute
}
```

and what is the correct way to pass multiple values to a single param in URL.

Comment: ?pageSources=A&pageSources=B&pageSources=C

Comment: You can pass whole object in @RequestBody Like :- @GetMapping("search")
public ResponseEntity<SearchResponseWrapper> fetchSearchResults(@RequestBody SearchCriteria searchCriteria) {
}

Comment: @BipilRaut no, you can't. GET requests don't have a body.